# matching substring beginning with special characters without using external commands

Tags: fish

I would like a function, abc123, which is called as:

```
abc123 -std=c++17 -Wall -lstdc++ -lpthread -o xxx xxx.cpp yyy.cpp
```

I would like to collect all substrings beginning with "-l" in the arguments.

Here is what I am running into:

```
%> echo (string match "l*" (string split " " "std=c++17 Wall lstdc++ lpthread o xxx xxx.cpp"))
%> lstdc++ lpthread
```

This is fine.  But the following will result in an error as the hyphons are interpreted as options:

```
echo (string match "-l*" (string split " " "-std=c++17 -Wall -lstdc++ -lpthread -o xxx xxx.cpp"))
```

Comment: In addition to Glenn's answer you might find the new `argparse` command (fish 2.7.0 or newer) useful for this type of problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just need to add `--` to separate options from arguments:

```
string match -- "-l*" (string split -- " " "-std=c++17 -Wall -lstdc++ -lpthread -o xxx xxx.cpp")
# ...........^^.....................^^
```

```
-lstdc++
-lpthread
```

Comment: Could you point to where this is documented, for future use - I missed it completely.

Comment: From http://fishshell.com/docs/current/commands.html#string: "Arguments beginning with - are normally interpreted as switches; -- causes the following arguments not to be treated as switches even if they begin with -.".